# Error: CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have a problem -

> System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpClient,
> string, T, System.Threading.CancellationToken)' and
> 'System.Net.Http.Json

```
private async Task Add()
{
    using (var msg = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<Feedback>("/api/feedbacks", newcust, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None))
    {
        if (msg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            custs.Add(await msg.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Feedback>());
            newcust.title = newcust.rating = newcust.comment = null;
        }
    }

    if (ValidReCAPTCHA)
    {
        var response = await reCAPTCHAComponent.GetResponseAsync();
        try
        {
            ServerVerificatiing = true;
            StateHasChanged();
            await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/sample", new SampleAPIArgs { reCAPTCHAResponse = response });
            Navigation.NavigateTo("/valid");
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            await JS.InvokeAsync<object>("alert", e.Message);
            ServerVerificatiing = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshoot Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL874.png)

Comment: Please post code as text, not as screenshot

Comment: Also the error message: please post as text.
What type is `Http`? What type is `newcust`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync
```

Instead of

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync
```

You may need some of these using:

```
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
```

Remove any reference to `System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions`
Below is code to install `System.Net.Http.Json`, if not installed

```
Install-Package System.Net.Http.Json -Version 5.0.0
```

Comment: what if I cant remove reference to either (I am using GetFromJsonAsync() because)? How can I invoke one of the two PostAsJsonAsync using static instance of HttpClient? e.g. HttpClientInstance.PostAsJsonAsync

Comment: @gawkface any progress on this, I have the same issue

Comment: @Haukland from what I found in my archive (cant seem to remember from back then so dug up some code), I ended up using HttpClient.SendAsync() methods (and hence did not face the original problem any longer)

Comment: @gawkface I ended up doing `await HttpClientJsonExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync(httpClient, rel_path, request, cancellationToken);` instead of `httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(rel_path, request, cancellationToken`. If wanted, you could use `HttpClientExtensions` instead of the Json version

Comment: Same problem and same solution. Looks like a bug, because I don't have any references to `HttpClientExtensions`. The problem appears only if I pass cancellationToken.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Http.PostAsJsonAsync` are found in 2 namespaces - take a look at what the error message actually says.

You must qualify the name more in order for the compiler to know which one you want to use. Otherwise you must remove one of the conflicting `using`s.

Like *PMF* and *Klaus* said in their comments - please post code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "implicit usings" (which adds both namespaces) try to change your call by adding explicit `options: null` parameter to force using the `HttpClientJsonExtensions` (there is the decompiled code from theirs):

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<TValue>(this HttpClient client, string? requestUri, TValue value, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    => client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUri, value, options: null, cancellationToken);``
```